# Query count not support in spring batch throws unexcepted error

Tags: sql, kotlin, spring-batch

> I want to count matches played by an individual team by calling the
> SQL query in my spring batch project . I use count query but it throws
> this type of issue

```
<expression>, ALL, DISTINCT or identifier expected, got '*'
```

> JobCompleteNotification.kt

```
@Transactional
    override fun afterJob(jobExecution: JobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() === BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results")
            val teamData: MutableMap<String, Team> = HashMap()
            em!!.createQuery(
                "select m.team1, count(*) from Match m group by m.team1",
                Array<Any>::class.java
            )
                .resultList
                .stream()
                .map { e: Array<Any> ->
                    Team(
                        e[0] as String, e[1] as Long
                    )
                }
                .forEach { team: Team -> teamData[team.teamName.toString()] = team }
            em!!.createQuery(
                "select m.team2, count(*) from Match m group by m.team2",
                Array<Any>::class.java
            )
                .resultList
                .stream()
                .forEach { e: Array<Any> ->
                    val team = teamData[e[0] as String]
                    team?.totalMatches = team!!.totalMatches + e[1] as Long
                }
            em!!.createQuery(
                "select m.matchWinner, count(*) from Match m group by m.matchWinner",
                Array<Any>::class.java
            )
                .resultList
                .stream()
                .forEach { e: Array<Any> ->
                    val team = teamData[e[0] as String]
                    team?.wins = e[1] as Long//.setTotalWins(e[1] as Long)
                }
            teamData.values.forEach(Consumer { team: Team? -> em!!.persist(team) })
            teamData.values.forEach(Consumer { team: Team? -> println(team) })
        }
    }
```

> I got above type of issue every where where I used the SQL Query in
> this function

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the asterisk in `count(*)` is not expected in the [JPQL](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group) using aggregates and `GROUP BY`.

Try using the table alias within the count function:

```kotlin
em!!.createQuery(
    "select m.matchWinner, count(m) from Match m group by m.matchWinner",
    Array<Any>::class.java
) //...
```